After disabling msi modules products disapper from category page
I disabled the MSI module on my Magento store version 2.4.2-p2, and everything seemed fine. However, upon testing the website, I discovered that products were no longer appearing on my category pages.
Here are the steps I followed:

Disable MSI modules

php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist --clear-static-content

Executed Magento commands

php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento ind:reset
php bin/magento ind:reindex
php bin/magento cac:flush

Could you please verify the salable quantity of your products?

Check for application errors. It seems product collections might be throwing some error
